# Can't read past EOF in C

Tags: c, fgets, eof, getline

Essentially a `tail -f` implementation: I'm updating a program that works fine on an older system that will continuously read an open file: after EOF, wait for the file to grow and keep reading. On newer systems, it is not able to read the file past EOF and I can't understand why. I stripped out all unrelated code and am able to reproduce with the following simplified example, which is nearly identical to the pattern [given here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19539650).

```
// COMPILE WITH: gcc a.c -o a.out
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
//----------------------------------------------------------------
  char* file_path = "/var/log/mail.log"; // any file that's active
  int seek_to_head = 0;
  int seek_to_tail = 1;

  int loop_sleep_seconds = 4;
  int use_getline = 1; // if 0, uses fgets()
//----------------------------------------------------------------

  size_t line_size_fgets = 1024;
  char line_fgets[line_size_fgets];
  char* line = NULL;
  size_t line_size = 0;

  // Open the file
  FILE* FILE_HANDLE;
  if (!(FILE_HANDLE = fopen(file_path, "r"))) {
    printf("Failed to open file [%s]: %s\n", file_path, strerror(errno));
    return 1;
  }

  // Unbuffer input
  if (setvbuf(FILE_HANDLE, NULL, _IONBF, 0) != 0)
  // if (setvbuf(FILE_HANDLE, NULL, _IOLBF, 0) != 0)
  {
    printf("Failed to unbuffer\n");
    return 1;
  }

  // Seek to head
  if (seek_to_head) {
    if (fseek(FILE_HANDLE, 0, SEEK_SET)) {
      printf("Failed to seek to beginning of file\n");
      return 1;
    }
    printf("Seek to start of file -- SUCCESS\n");
  }

  // Seek to tail
  if (seek_to_tail) {
    if (fseek(FILE_HANDLE, 0, SEEK_END)) {
      printf("Failed to seek to end of file\n");
      return 1;
    }
    printf("Seek to end of file -- SUCCESS\n");
  }

  printf("Begin tracking file %s\n", file_path);

  // Main loop
  while (1) {

    // Read all remaining file contents til exhausted for now
    if (use_getline)
      while (getline(&line, &line_size, FILE_HANDLE) != -1)
        printf("\nLINE: %s\n", line);
    else
      while (fgets(line_fgets, line_size_fgets, FILE_HANDLE) != NULL)
        printf("\nLINE: %s\n", line_fgets);

    // Make sure there wasn't an error reading file
    if (ferror(FILE_HANDLE)) {
      printf("Failed to read from file [%s]: %s\n", file_path, strerror(errno));
      return 1;
    }

    // Pause for file to grow (inotify code goes here)
    sleep(loop_sleep_seconds);
    printf("Try reading again\n");

  }

  free(line);
  printf("Exiting\n");
  return 0;

}
```

This example has a variable you can flip to use getline() or fgets() but both have the same problem on newer systems I've tried. If seeking to the beginning of the file, all the file contents are printed to date, but anything after that is never printed. If seeking to the end of the file, no output is ever produced. The real program polls for file changes instead of sleeping and I confirmed that the poll is working correctly, but that seems unrelated; the errant behavior is the same both ways.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: What exact OS version(s) are involved?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Sorry, I don't see that example doing anything with the input stream (fp) except getc() and an error check. Does flushing stdout somehow clear the EOF state on the input FILE stream? My original program isn't printing anything out so that won't be an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can (and should) explicitly clear the EOF before attempting to read further data.  Something like:

```c
    // Pause for file to grow (inotify code goes here)
    if( feof( FILE_HANDLE ) )
    {
        clearerr( FILE_HANDLE ) ;
        sleep(loop_sleep_seconds);
        printf("Try reading again\n");
    }
```

Otherwise EOF will normally only be cleared by call to one of rewind, fseek, fsetpos and freopen on the *same stream*.  So you could alternatively or `setpos` to the current position.

Comment: That was it, thank you! None of the how-tos, manpages or examples I found referenced that at all, so thank you. Do you happen to know why it would have been working without clearing EOF state on older systems?

Comment: The documentation of `clearerr()` refers to it. The trick I think is to familiarise yourself with the whole library - perhaps not in detail, but at least to get an idea of the scope of it, so you know something exists to look up the detail when you need it.  You would perhaps need to specify the platform and library ( and versions) to ascertain why it previously appeared to work, but it would have been relying on either undefined, implementation defined or just plain erroneous behaviour.

Comment: It stopping working is either a change of library, change of specification or bug fix exposing what was in the original code a bug.

Comment: ... to be fair, some references say very little. https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/clearerr/ expands on the rather terse definition in Linux man pages for example.

Comment: @MeSteve, the spec is actually a bit ambiguous here.  Except for `fgetc()`, all the stdio input functions express conditional behavior in terms of "if end-of-file is encountered" or "if the stream as it end-of-file" (and `fgetc()` was specified the same way in C89).  Every version of the spec attributes an end-of-file indicator to each stream, and I have always taken the intent to be that the indicator can be tested to avoid attempting to read from the underlying data source once EOF has been reached, but the spec explicitly mandates that only for `fgetc()`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: `"but the spec explicitly mandates that only for fgetc()"` -- This statement is incorrect. [§7.21.3 ¶11](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.3p11) sentence 3 states the following: `"The byte input functions read characters from the stream as if by successive calls to the fgetc function."` According to [§7.21.1 ¶5](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.1p5), `fgets` is one of the "byte input functions". However, I agree that the descriptions of some of the byte input functions is misleading.

Comment: Thank you @AndreasWenzel, I overlooked that.  That explains why C99 updated only the description of `fgetc()` to refer to the end-of-file indicator, leaving all the other descriptions the same.  C89 still has the ambiguity I described, however, and perhaps that's related to why code similar to the OP's worked as expected on some older C implementations (accepting, for the sake of argument, the OP's claim that it did).

Comment: @AndreasWenzel and @ Clifford: Thank you for the interesting discussion. The example code was confirmed working at the time of this post on both RHEL and Debian flavors that were released near or more than 10 years ago. My much more layperson's complaint is that there is not more clarity on the manpage of any read functions that EOF is a state that can be cleared at all. Now I know, thank you!